# rails - access method in app/helpers/xhelper.rb from lib/x.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to access method defined in xhelper module of app/helpers/xhelper.rb file. it needs to accessed in x.rb file under lib folder.

app/helpers/xhelper.rb file look like this:

```
module Xhelper
 def method_to_be_used
   p 'ok'
 end
end
```

lib/x.rb file look like this

```
require 'xhelper'

class X
include Xhelper
  def x
    method_to_be_used
  end
end
```

i get below error: 
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `method_to_be_used' for X:Class

Comment: This code is not even valid ruby. ‘xhelper‘ is not constant as it does not start with a uppercase letter. You might think I'm splitting hairs here and that this is just code  you typed up for the question but it matters immensely for NoMethodErrors which are caused 99% of the time by programmer slop. We have no chance at all of spotting the actual issue when you just create a badly made stand in for the actual code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @max fixed module name

Comment: Its still not reproducible though. `require 'xhelper'` should actually be raising an error unless the file is in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in requiring the file.

The `require` requires the absolute path.
I try to use the `require_relative` as it takes the current path and start searching the file from that path. And it's cleaner.

So in your case -

**xhelper.rb**

```
module Xhelper
  def method_to_be_used
    p 'ok'
  end
end
```

**x.rb**

```
require_relative '../app/helpers/xhelper'

class X
  include Xhelper
  def x
    method_to_be_used
  end
end
```

Have a read at this [blog](https://medium.com/@ellishim/understanding-require-vs-require-relative-vs-require-all-80e3b26d89e6) for more in depth into the `require` of ruby.

Comment: There shouldn't be. I posted the answer bye generating it in my machine. Can you add your exact class and module to the question?

Comment: The problem here is not require at all. `app/helpers` is autoloaded in Rails. If it was problem the error would not be a NoMethodError, rather it would be missing constant or file error. I'm guessing the actual issue is a slop error that's not conveyed through the code in the question.

Comment: ok so. i fixed it. "include Xhelper" needed to placed outside Class. i dont know why yet. but seen an example somewhere in online. i cant remember from which rails version but in newer rails, seems like require is not required cause rails makes it accessible. posting my answer below.

Comment: require_relative statement is required - it seems.

Answer (score 0):

the complete answer that worked for me.

xhelper.rb

```
module Xhelper
  def method_to_be_used
    p 'ok'
  end
end
```

x.rb

```
require_relative '../app/helpers/xhelper'
include Xhelper

class X
  def x
    method_to_be_used
  end
end
```